# How to check that mongo ObjectID is valid in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson, objectid

I want to verify that the objectID is a valid mongoID string.

Currently I have:

```
import bson
try:
  bson.objectid.ObjectId(id)
except:
  pass # do something
```

I wanted to make my exception more specific, and it looks like [there is a solution](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/errors.html), but `except bson.objectid.InvalidId` ends up in `TypeError: id must be an instance of (str, unicode, ObjectId)`.

Ok, I tried to look further and [found is_valid method](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html) but `bson.is_valid(1)` results in another error `TypeError: BSON data must be an instance of a subclass of str`.

So how can I properly check if my objectID is valid?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you're confusing `bson.is_valid()` with `bson.objectid.ObjectId.is_valid()`.

The latter works for me.

```
bson.objectid.ObjectId.is_valid('54f0e5aa313f5d824680d6c9')
=> True
bson.objectid.ObjectId.is_valid('54f0e5aa313f5d824680d')
=> False
```

Its implementation is more or less what you'd expect:

```
@classmethod
def is_valid(cls, oid):
    try:
        ObjectId(oid)
        return True
    except (InvalidId, TypeError):
        return False
```

Comment: Why the type error?

Answer (score 3):

This is what works for me :

```
from bson import ObjectId

if ObjectId.is_valid("5bb3314919802578051ccf86"):
  return True
else:
  return False
```